# Site gives 500 error or malformed page in place of WSOD and useful error reporting

Tags: 7

I don't think I have encountered this before. Generally if there's a php error on page, I'm met with a WSOD. With error reporting on, the error, file, line number, etc are displayed on the page.

With this site, the site either returns a 500 error (if the error is in hook_form_alter, for example), or the page will load partially up to the point of the error and display sans stylesheet/other resources (if the error is in a template file).

Any ideas why this might be and how to change it over to expected behavior?

Comment: Did you look in admin/config/development/logging to ensure error reporting is set to "none"?

Comment: @longboardnode it is indeed set to "none". Changing it to another setting doesn't appear to change anything related to this issue.

Comment: check your settings.php file, does it have any error reporting config? see this [DO post](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/creating-custom-modules/show-all-errors-while-developing) about turning them on (so you want to replace TRUE with FALSE, and/or 2 to 0 in this setting`$conf['error_level'] = 0;` to turn them off).

Comment: Add $config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'all'; in your settings file

Comment: I've added your suggestions to settings.php and now have `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
$conf['error_level'] = 0;
$config['system.logging']['error_level'] = 'all';` and am still not seeing any errors on screen.

Comment: My bad, 0 should be 2: `$conf['error_level'] = 2;`  Also, can you `dpm($messages)` inside your template.php and see if any of the php errors are printed that way?

Comment: No change with `$conf['error_level'] = 2`. `print_r($messages)` at the top of both child and parent template.php has no effect, although `print_r('some text')` does display, so I'd assume this means either `$messages` doesn't exist or hasn't yet been created.

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? Sometimes this is more useful than Drupal logs...

Comment: It's a local setup with MAMP, so I do have access to the logs. However, these particular errors don't appear to be logging anywhere that I can find. FWIW, MAMP is set to show/log all errors.

Comment: @Mrweiner it seems that some theme or custom module function is overriding or resetting the $messages session variable with every page load. Can you search through your custom theme/modules code for "$messages" maybe we can debug it this way. You can also try to `drupal_set_message('test');` and then `print_r(drupal_get_messages());` in your template.php and see if that helps.

Comment: You should try `sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @longboardnode thanks for all of your suggestions, but it turns out somebody had hardcoded hiding all errors in the middle of settings.php. yeesh...

Comment: (facepalm!) we've all been there... lol! and you're welcome glad you were able to sort it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that somebody had previously hardcoded turning off error reporting somewhere in the middle of settings.php. Removed those lines and now all errors are showing up as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Fixing such errors is a panic, as in comments you have tried php debugging.

Below tries may help:

1- Try to install new drupal site locally to ensure that your machine and required programs for drupal "If you don't have any working drupal site" works fine, If you faced problems in the installation fix them till you have successful installation.

2- Try to flush cache and running cron from the admin interface if it works or using drush by drush you can see latest log messages using commands "wd-list, ws".

3- Implement [hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_init/7.x) in any custom module and print any message after that call [drupal exit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_exit/7.x) to see tha messages in the browser.

4-disable "without uninstall in order not to loose configurations" last enabled custom or contributed modules, If you have drush installed try

> drush dis Module_name -y

Or from phpmyadmin

> Delete from system where name='Module_name';

I used these steps before to solve similar situation and I remember it was from one the contrib modules.

If you still have the problem these guides may help.

[Fixing white screens step by step](https://www.drupal.org/node/482956)

[Blank pages or "white screen of death" (WSOD)](https://www.drupal.org/node/158043)